# Python - Remove rows and columns in Matrix where all values are 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Matrix that I created from a dataframe and I want to remove all columns where every value in it is a 0.

I have seen examples using dropna `df2.loc[:, (df2 != 0).any(axis=0)]` but it doesnt do anything with my dataframe.

This is how I created my Matrix:

```
a = ['Psychology','Education','Social policy','Sociology','Pol. sci. & internat. studies','Development studies','Social anthropology','Area Studies','Science and Technology Studies','Law & legal studies','Economics','Management & business studies','Human Geography','Environmental planning','Demography','Social work','Tools, technologies & methods','Linguistics','History']
final_df = new_df[new_df['Subject'].isin(a)]

ctrs = {location: Counter(gp.GrantRefNumber) for location, gp in final_df.groupby('Subject')}

ctrs = list(ctrs.items())
overlaps = [(loc1, loc2, sum(min(ctr1[k], ctr2[k]) for k in ctr1))
    for i, (loc1, ctr1) in enumerate(ctrs, start=1)
    for (loc2, ctr2) in ctrs[i:] if loc1 != loc2]
overlaps += [(l2, l1, c) for l1, l2, c in overlaps]

df22 = pd.DataFrame(overlaps, columns=['Loc1', 'Loc2', 'Count'])
df22 = df22.set_index(['Loc1', 'Loc2'])
df22 = df22.unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)

#the end part of the next line filters the top 'x' amount.
b = np.sort(np.unique(df22.values.ravel()))[-20:]
df2 = df22.where(df22.isin(b),0.0)
```

Interestingly (or not), when I type `df2.columns`, I get:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'Count'], [u'Area Studies', u'Demography', u'Development studies', u'Economics', u'Education', u'Environmental planning', u'History', u'Human Geography', u'Law & legal studies', u'Linguistics', u'Management & business studies', u'Pol. sci. & internat. studies', u'Psychology', u'Science and Technology Studies', u'Social anthropology', u'Social policy', u'Social work', u'Sociology', u'Tools, technologies & methods']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]],
           names=[None, u'Loc2'])
```

Which might be why I am struggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for `True` of columns which contains `0` with `~` for invert condition:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'C':[0,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[0,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[0,3,6,9,2,4]})

print (df)
   B  C  D  E
0  0  0  0  0
1  0  8  3  3
2  0  9  5  6
3  0  4  7  9
4  0  2  1  2
5  0  3  0  4

df = df.loc[~df.eq(0).all(axis=1), ~df.eq(0).all()]
print (df)
   C  D  E
1  8  3  3
2  9  5  6
3  4  7  9
4  2  1  2
5  3  0  4
```

Comment: Hey Jezrael, just tried both your examples and it removed everything from the dataframe and just left 'Loc1 and the list of disciplines underneath (i.e. deleted all the numbers and the column headers? I do have some columns with numbers in, so it shouldnt have deleted all of them.

Comment: I was reading the requirement as remove columns where all the values were 0 - this removes those where any value is 0...

Comment: Ye, I meant ALL the values were 0 in a column :)

Comment: I am very thankful for the help. Is there a version for doing the rows too? As I have removed the columns but the rows which have only 0's have remained? :)